# Well-orderings and the perfect set property

Tags: set-theory, descriptive-set-theory, well-orders

From a wellordering of an uncountable set of reals, Bernstein constructed a set of reals without the perfect set property. My question is, does an uncountable well-ordering itself violate the perfect set property?  Equivalently, if $W \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ is a well-ordering of some set of reals, must $W$ be thin?

Comment: What do you mean by "thin"? That it doesn't contain a perfect set? I also assume that we work in the context of $\sf ZF$ or $\sf ZF+DC$?

Comment: Yes, by "thin" I mean it doesn't contain a perfect set.  You can assume choice if necessary, but my guess would be that it doesn't matter.

Comment: Well, if $|W|<\frak c$ then yes. You might want to rule that out immediately. Otherwise, good question.

Comment: Yes, if $|W|<\mathfrak{c}$ then it is trivially true.  But as it stands the question asks about all $W$.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since you said, in a comment, "you can assume choice if necessary", I'll assume choice and fix a well-ordering $W$ of all the reals such that all the negative reals precede all the positive reals.  Then $W$ includes the perfect set $\{(x,y):x<0<y\}$.

On the other hand, some such use of the axiom of choice is needed.  It's consistent with ZF + DC that every well-orderable set of reals is countable.

Comment: I am confused. How is $\{(x,y)\mid x<0<y\}$ closed? Maybe you mean that this set contains perfect sets?

Comment: Yes, I meant that it has perfect subsets.

Comment: D'oh! I was afraid it might be something so simple.  Thank you.